# How to use readAttributes method?

Tags: java

I don't know how to use `readAttributes` method of `Files` class, to access all the file attributes at once. My problem is that I want to print all the attributes in bulk, without calling methods.

I don't want to call methods one by one, as shown below:

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());

System.out.println("isDirectory: " + attr.isDirectory());
System.out.println("isOther: " + attr.isOther());
System.out.println("isRegularFile: " + attr.isRegularFile());
System.out.println("isSymbolicLink: " + attr.isSymbolicLink());
System.out.println("size: " + attr.size());
```

I would like to access all the BasicFileAttribute at once.
If we cannot access all attributes with readAttributes at once,then is there any other way to do this.

Comment: the framework has been *designed* to work like that and it does so for most of us. Could you explicitly state why you *don't want to call methods one by one*? these methods dont perform any disk IO they are simple getters and return already fetched values. so what is the issue?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(attr);`, see what you get. If you don't like it then you will have to form a string yourself, but still you would have to call all the methods.

Comment: I tried it but i get this "sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributes@d93b30"       @Bhesh

Comment: You might be interested in using the other method [`Map<String,Object> readAttributes(Path path, String attributes, LinkOption... options)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29)

Comment: Thanks this method worked for printing all attributes at once.@BheshGurung

Comment: It seems that this method returns a map now in java 8 compiler settings. I am not able to `BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);` because the method returns a map and not a BasicFileAttributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

public class ListOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\kk.txt");
        Map f  = Files.readAttributes(path, "*");
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is another example of how to use `readAttributes()` method  of the class [**`BasicFileAttributes`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) class:

```
   Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\jorgesys\\workspaceJava\\myfile.txt");
    BasicFileAttributes attr;
    try {
     attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
     System.out.println("Creation time: " + attr.creationTime());
     System.out.println("Last access time: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
     System.out.println("Last modified time: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
    } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("oops un error! " + e.getMessage());
    }
```